# Borrar valores duplicados de un stripos

Tags: php, json, array

Tengo una pregunta.

**Contexto:**
A petición de la parte interesada, estoy trabajando Php con Json  para guardar los archivos. y Tengo un buscador que me busca la palabra "texto" dentro de los json que están en un direcctorio *[ con stripos($contenido, "texto") ]* y los muestra en pantalla.

**Aquí el problema:**
stripos busca varias veces la misma palabra dentro del archivo json, y eso hace que se me repita el valor. Cómo le hago para que solo búsque una palabra, sea la primera o la última, o para que no me muestre los datos repetidos.

**Código utilizado**

```
    if(isset($_GET['buscar']))
{
    $busquedaa = $_GET['buscar'];
    $files = glob('datos/*'); 

    foreach($files as $file)
    { 
      if(is_file($file))
        {
          $json = file_get_contents($file);
          $deco = json_decode($json);

          foreach($deco as $clave=>$valor)
            {
              $contenido = $valor;
              if (stripos($contenido, $busquedaa ) !==false)
                {    
                $objetos = $deco;
                var_dump($objetos);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Notas**
*(1)*Lo que quiero es que no me muestre el contenido repetidas veces si encuentra la palabra varias veces en el mismo archivo . Con una vez es suficiente.
*(2)*Estoy abierto a cualquier sugerencia.
*(3)*No puedo usar JQuerry o JS o cualquier otro, solo Php y Html.
*(4)*No puedo usar base de datos.
*(5)*Insensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas.
*(6)*Debe ser que contenga la palabra, no palabra exacta.
*(7)*Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo tienes que *romper* (*break*) tu `foreach( )` mas interno y continuar con el mas externo. Con ello, solo te mostrará **la primera** aparición:

```
if( isset( $_GET['buscar'] ) ) {
  $busquedaa = $_GET['buscar'];
  $files = glob( 'datos/*' );

  foreach( $files as $file ) { 
    if( is_file( $file ) ) {
      $json = json_decode( file_get_contents( $file ) );

      foreach( $json as $valor )
        if( stripos( $valor, $busquedaa ) !== false ) {
          var_dump( $json );
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Dios mío!! Sii! Funcionó a la perfección!! Cuantas noches sin dormir buscando esto (ocho, para ser exacto)!!! Gracias Bro!!!

Comment: ¡¡ Pues haber preguntado antes, hombre !! Aquí estamos, un placer :-)

Comment: @AmilcarAngeles Una pregunta ... tus archivos JSON ... ¿ son objetos `{ ... }`, *arrays* `[ ..., ..., ... ]`, o un *array* de objetos `[ { ... }, { ... }, ... ]` ? Que igual podemos optimizar esto un poco :-)

Comment: Son objetos, object(stdClass)... (Disculpa la tardanza, me quedé probando la app, aún no podía creer que fuera tan simple.